# How do I add a new property to an empty object that is stored in a component's state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, state

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        lists: [], // this holds the name of each list
        items: {} // this property names of this object are the names of the lists; their values are arrays of the items in each list
    };
}

handleAddList(s) {
    var curState = this.state.items;

    this.setState(prevState => ({
        lists: [...prevState.lists, s],
        items: //I am having trouble figuring out how I can use "s" and set that as a new property of this items object.
    }))
}
```

I want `items` to get a new property whose *name* is from `s` and whose value is, initially, `[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do the same thing you did with `lists`: You make a *new* object with all of the old properties, along with the change. Since you've said (in a comment) that you want `{dog: []}` where `dog` is the value of `s`, you'd do it like this:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  lists: [...prevState.lists, s],
  items: {...prevState.items, [s]: []}
}))
```

The `items` part of that is a combination of two things:

1. The `...` is [spread properties](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread). It's conceptually the same as array spread (what you're using with `lists`) but it's new: The proposal is currently at Stage 3 but will be at Stage 4 quite soon. It's been transpiled by Babel for well over a year, and is natively supported by V8 in Chrome and SpiderMonkey in Firefox (not behind any flag).
2. The `[s]` is a *computed property name*. It creates a property whose name is the **value** of `s`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply... I tried that but it gives me this when I console.log(this.state.items)... {s: "dog"}... the result I want is {dog: []} dog being the value of s.

Comment: @aclspy: Ah, then you want a computed property name in addition to property spread. I've updated the above.

Comment: Thanks T.J. your answer is exactly what I am looking for!